# What is the default password for Windows Storage Server 2008?

Tags: windows, storage-server

After freshly installing Windows Storage Server 2008, you're presented with a login screen where the system installation process hasn't prompted you for any kind of a password.

What's the default password for Windows Storage Server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“wSS2008!”

(My understanding is that asking for information like this is the proper way to 'archive' it on the StackOverflow/Serverfault systems.. which is why I've answered my own question here..)

[Source](http://resume.jimmarch.com/2009/05/windows-storage-server-2008-rc-default-password/)